# Assign variable names from list of files keeping list format

Tags: r, list, assign

I am opening a list of netcdf files from a folder looping over them such that:

```
nfiles <- 10
datL <- list.files(/home/myname/filedir/,pattern='*nc')
for (i in 1:nfiles){
    dat = nc_open(datL[[i]])
```

To extract the variables and keep their names as in the netcdf files I do:

```
    allvars <- as.list(names(dat[['var']]))
    for (k in 1:length(unlist(allvars)) ) {
        assign(allvars[[k]],ncvar_get(dat(allvars[[k]])) } }
```

All the files have about 50 variables each, but most files have the same variable names. 
What I would like to do but just can't work out, is how to keep the list number in the naming of the variables. So, as an example, let's say that in the netcdf files, there is a variable called `rain`, `assign(allvars[[k]])` will simply assign the name `rain`. What I would like instead is for the variable name also to be assigned the list number such that it is `rain[[i]]`. `assign(paste0(allvars[[k]],as.list(i)),ncvar_get...etc)` writes the variables as `rain1`,`rain2` but I would prefer the `[[` format.

Comment: Instead of `list`ing and `unlist`ing, you could have kept it in a vector.  `allvars <- paste0(names(dat[['var']]), rain); for(k in seq_along(all_vars)) assign(allvars[k], ...`

Comment: @akrun I don't think this is doing what I'm asking. I've edited the question to try to be clearer.

Comment: Forget `assign`. It's a function for experts and not to be misused by beginners. Just put all these variables in a list, e.g., `L <- list(); L[[allvars[k]]] <- ...`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. It still doesn't do what I asked for, but I can work with it. I need the variable name to keep the list number of the loop over nfiles. By modifying your suggestion such as `L <-list(); for (i in 1:nfiles){ L[[i]] <- list() ; ... ; L[[i]][[allvars[[k]]]] <- ncvar_get...` the list number is kept such that I'd obtain `L[[i]]$rain`, but not `rain[[i]]` which would be simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list2env](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/list2env)() to assign a list of named variables to the global environment, for example:

```
l <- list(a = 1, b = 2:4, p = pi, ff = gl(3, 4, labels = LETTERS[1:3]))
list2env(l, .GlobalEnv)
ls()
[1] "a"  "b"  "ff" "l"  "p"
```

Also you might have a look at the book R for data science, and notably the section on [many models](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html). It introduces the concept of nested data frames which enable working with many similar sub-datasets and many sub-models.